# rails showing error while starting rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here i am trying to start ruby on rails server.but i am not able to start because of these following errors.

how can i solve this?

```
C:\Users\hazelnut\Desktop\wardrobe\wardrobe>rails server
Could not find gem 'tzinfo-data (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on thi
s machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

C:\Users\hazelnut\Desktop\wardrobe\wardrobe>bundle install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-
10.4.2.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (10.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'` succeeds before bundling.

C:\Users\hazelnut\Desktop\wardrobe\wardrobe>gem install rake
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rake' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect retur
ned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (
https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Comment: Please show output of `ruby -v` and `gem -v` commands.

Comment: Have you installed using DevKit? http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a common SSL issue.

Please see the error message:

certificate verify failed

The error message is because your system needs a new SSL certificate.

Here's information about it:

http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html